# Difference of $y=1/x$ and its two points for $x$ integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to prove that the line joining the points $(n,\frac1n)$ and $(n+1,\frac{1}{n+1})$ lies above the graph $y=\frac1x$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$ by the following method. The equation for the line is $$y_l=\dfrac{-1}{n(n+1)}x+\dfrac{2n+1}{n(n+1)},$$ so I need to prove that $\Delta y = y_l -\frac1x$ is positive for $x \in (n,n+1)$. Considering $n<x<n+1$ and thus $-n>-x>-(n+1)$ and $-\frac{1}{n}<\frac{-1}{x}<-\frac{1}{n+1}$; thus $$-\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}n+\dfrac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{n}<\Delta y<-\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}(n+1)+\dfrac{2n+1}{n(n+1)}-\frac{1}{n+1} \implies -\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}<\Delta y<\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)} .$$

Why this method which *must* arrive at $\Delta y>0$ fails so? Why the above method is limited to lead the answer?

Comment: The function $x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ is strictly convex on $x>0$.

Comment: @copper.hat, yes but I want to know why the calculation above fails?

Comment: The left hand side of the estimate of $\Delta y$ above is $0$, I think you made a mistake in computation...

Comment: @copper.hat, No I calculated for many times and still the lower bound falls below zero!

Comment: Yes. Try again. Generally $-n+2n+1-(n+1) = 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what 'doing some algebra' did, so it is hard to answer the
question as asked?

You want to show that ${2n+1-x \over n (n+1)} -{1 \over x} \ge 0$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$. Multiply across by $xn (n+1)$ to get the equivalent
$-x^2+(1-2n)x-n(n+1) =-(x-n)(x-(n+1)) \ge 0$.

Note that this is a concave quadratic in $x$, and has roots $n,n+1$, hence is
strictly positive for $x \in (n,n+1)$.

Comment: Your answer is absolutely right, but still I am confused why my calculations doesn't lead to $\Delta y \ge 0?$ I edited the question. Thanks a lot :)